# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/attachments/photos/000/000/019/thumb/default.png")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, production-environment

I'm using paperclip to upload images and its working fine on development, but on production server its throwing error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/attachments/photos/000/000/019/thumb/default.png")
```

I've tried everything to fix it, but nothing helped me. Below is my attachment model

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :testimonial
  has_attached_file :photo , :styles => { :thumb => "62x84!" },
                :path => ":rails_root/public/photo_attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                :url => "/photo_attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif']
end
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Change `:rails_root` to `Rails.root`

```
:path => "#{Rails.root}/public/photo_attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

With this change, whatever new images you upload will work but not the old images because the image path already stored in db is incorrect.

Comment: but its storing image on development environment, will this make any difference on production?

Comment: compare the image path that is being stored in the development DB and production DB, they both must be different

Comment: your `:url` options also seems to be incorrect . It should be `:url => "/public/photo_attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"`